# My Background image doesn't show up and is not inspected in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used mozila and I try to "inspect element" to see if my background image is there. The inspect element even doesn't show the css style mark up like `background-image: blah blah;` at all.

I am very sure that I have written the code correctly:

```
       background-image: url ('social-icon/button.png');
```

Some discussion out there said that it may be caused of "javascript" and adviced to disable the javascript, but I don't know how to do that. Eventhough it is true that the problem is the javascript and it means that I can't use Javascript in my html file, it will be worse.

I am just confused?

**EDITED :p**

LOL, THE PROBLEM IS BECAUSE I HAVE A SPACE BETWEEN URL AND THE SOURCE. IT SHOULD BE LIKE

```
        url{there is no space here}('social-icon/button.png');
```

It's so funny how we all can't see a little problem when our focus is to the another point of the question. :D :D :D

Comment: Is your image in the root folder?

Comment: if even the css markup doesn't show-up it shouldn't be a javascript problem, maybe it's some sort of a browser cache problem? Did you try to clean your cache?

Comment: It looks like you image is nested in the css folder. You should try with `'../social-icon/button.png'` or `'../images/social-icon/button.png'`.

Comment: the folder of the image is in the folder where the html file is.

Comment: @pid thank you man, but it still doesn't work. :( I think it's true that it is the javascript problem.

Comment: @levon, I have not tried to clear the browser cache yet because I doubt it if it is the problem of the browser. The other css mark up is showing up in the inspected element except that background-image.

Comment: LOL, THE PROBLEM IS BECAUSE I HAVE A SPACE BETWEEN URL AND THE SOURCE. IT SHOULD BE LIKE 'url{there is no space here}('social-icon/button.png');'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your css file correctly linked in the .html? I understand it as you have your img as a background-image in css?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourCss.css">
```

It's a long shot, but try with removing the image part,

```
background: url('social-icon/button.png');
```

Comment: Of course. All the css style is inspected except that background image.

Answer (score 0):

try this (copy-paste this code)

```
background-image: url(../social-icon/button.png);
```

Tell the results!

Comment: It still doesn't show up the background image, even in the "inspected element" the css mark up is still not showing up too.